# Merging rows with different columns into one row with distinct information from both

Tags: mysql, sql, merge, row

Is there a way to merge rows with some values that are same and one different value into one row, but different values should be shown as separate columns.

For example:

| id | pos | qty | item |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 5 | 100 | PO111 |
| 3 | 5 | 50 | PO112 |

Outcome should be:

| id | pos | qty | item | item2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 5 | 150 | PO111 | PO112 |

I was only able to find that you can put item's in one single column, but I need to have it separate ones.

The first table can contain more than two rows with same id and pos (It can be 3,4,5 etc. ). Table is being ordered by ID and POS. Qty is SUM(qty) it is a quantity of products. It is the same product, but it is stored in different items. I need a row to show same product but different items it is stored in  and SUM(qty).

Comment: share the logic of item separation in two columns

Comment: Define `easy`, and what did you try to solve this basic SQL question?  HINT: some of the functions mentioned here might be used: [Aggregate Function Descriptions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html)

Comment: Please explain what should happen when you have 3 (or more) records for `id=3`, or will that _never happen_ ?

Comment: Updated with more information